# Best practices to define custom error codes for an API

Tags: java, python, api, rest, software-design

We are planning to develop an API. There are so many cases that a request can be considered as a bad request.
For this, We have planned to send a JSON object with `error code`, `error`,
and `additional info`

I have put the sample case here when a user sends an illumination image. We considered as this request is bad request and send the following JSON

```json
{
"ErrorCode": 10000,
"Error": "Detected uneven illumination image",
"Additional Info": "Prefer to change the image location"
}
```

1. Is  our JSON object format is good or we need to add the HTTP Error code like 400/404
2. How to select this custom error code? We are planning to take the error code number from 10000.

Can someone please help us or **provide some trustful resources**?

Comment: Why from 10000?

Comment: Randomly we took this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [Stripe API](https://stripe.com/docs/api) they also use [error codes](https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes) (`code`) to explain different `4xx` errors